# Register a generated uniqid in database

Tags: php, database

Today I need your help. I'm actually coding a register form and for each new registration I generate a key with the **uniqid()** function.

The problem is when I try to insert my generated key in my database I've this error:

> Erreur: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES('','test','test','test@test.com','7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494' at line 1

The field for the key in my database is set to **VARCHAR(90)**.

I've looked for an answer on Google or here but **I haven't found anyone with the same issue**.

Does anyone knows where is my problem please ?

Thks,
Antho

**EDIT:**

Here is my SQL Request:

```
$key = uniqid();

try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(id,name,firstname,mail,pass,status,avatar,key) VALUES('','$name','$firstname','$mail','$pass','$status','$avatar','$key')";
    $req = $db->exec($sql);

    echo 'OK';
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Erreur: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: after writing your sql query we can say something.

Comment: Can you add the whole query ?

Comment: can you share your query with us for better grip of problem?

Comment: If your columns are quoted, it appears that you may be missing a quote at the end of `key` or missing a comma. (just guessing though, you'd need to show us your full INSERT query).

Comment: I've edited my question with my INSERT query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe KEY is a mysql reserved word. Try escaping it with

```
`key`
```

Comment: It is, as in `PRIMARY KEY`. For reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html